# Git difference between ignore dir/* and dir/ and dir

Tags: git

I was surprised when I did `git pull` and an untracked directory got deleted.

I'm wondering if it is related to my `.gitignore` file.

For that particular folder, I have:

`/path/to/folder/*`

Whereas for some other folders I have:

`/path/to/folder/`

Is there a difference, especially as pertains to what happens to the files in that folder when I do `git pull`?

Note: I backed up the files before hand, so I was able to restore them. But in the future I will need to be able to `git pull` without having this potential disaster on my hands.

Answer (score -2):

git doesnt track empty directory. Once you got some files in there and if you run git status it will show the dir/ as untracked. That means: anything in dir folder I am not tracking.

.gitignore file is used in git status: When you run git status it compares your working directory with Index and uses .gitignore to ignore the files mentioned.

When you run git pull- it runs fetch and merge. It will not remove your untracked directories and files but merges with incoming changes from remote.

Comment: `git pull` is as you say `fetch+merge` which does affect your working directory!

Comment: Well, a folder that was there before the pull was gone right afterwards. And git's output had thousands of lines starting with "delete mode". Seems like it deleted.